# if $\mu(A)>0$, and $f<g$ in $A$, then $\int_A f\ d\mu <\int_A g\ d \mu$

Tags: measure-theory

here is my doubt:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{T}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $f,g:X\to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ measurable functions (indeed with finite integral), and $A \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and
>   $$
> f(x)<g(x)\quad \forall x \in A
> $$
>   then $\int_A f\ d\mu<\int_A g\ d\mu$.

Any hint in order to prove (or disprove) it would be wellcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\mu(A) > 0$ and $f > 0$ on A.  Put
$$E_n = \{\omega\in A| f(\omega) \ge 1/n\}.$$
Then $E_n \uparrow A.$  Since $\mu(A) >0$ there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$\mu(E_n) > 0$.  What can you say about
$$\int_{E_n} f\, d\mu?$$

Comment: Then $\int_{E_n}f\ d\mu\geq 1/n \mu(E_n)>0$, and as $\int_A f\ d\mu\geq \int_{E_n}f\ d\mu$, I can conclude :B